# finding sum of values in a nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, machine-learning, python-3.3

I have around around 20000 text files, numbered 5.txt,10.txt and so on..

I am storing the filepaths of these files in a list "list2" that i have created.

I also  have a text file "temp.txt" with a list of 500 words

```
vs
mln
money
```

and so on..

I am storing these words in another list "list" that i have created.

Now i create a nested dictionary d2[file][word]=frequency count of "word" in "file"

Now,

I need to iterate through these words for each text file as,

i am trying to get the following output :

```
filename.txt- sum(d[filename][word]*log(prob))
```

Here, filename.txt is of the form 5.txt,10.txt and so on...

"prob",which is a value that i have already  obtained

I basically need to find the sum of the inner keys'(words) values, (which is the frequency of the word) for every outer key(file).

Say:

```
d['5.txt']['the']=6
```

here "the" is my word and "5.txt" is the file.Now 6 is the number of times "the" occurs in "5.txt".

Similarly:

```
d['5.txt']['as']=2.
```

I need to find the sum of the dictionary values.

So,here for 5.txt: i need my answer to be :

```
6*log(prob('the'))+2*log(prob('as'))+...`(for all the words in list)
```

I need this to be done for all the files.

My problem lies in the part where I am supposed to iterate through the nested dictionary

```
import collections, sys, os, re

sys.stdout=open('4.txt','w')
from collections import Counter
from glob import glob

folderpath='d:/individual-articles'
folderpaths='d:/individual-articles/'
counter=Counter()
filepaths = glob(os.path.join(folderpath,'*.txt'))


#test contains: d:/individual-articles/5.txt,d:/individual,articles/10.txt,d:/individual-articles/15.txt and so on...
with open('test.txt', 'r') as fi:
    list2= [line.strip() for line in fi]


#temp contains the list of words
with open('temp.txt', 'r') as fi:
    list= [line.strip() for line in fi]


#the dictionary that contains d2[file][word]
d2 =defaultdict(dict)
for fil in list2:
    with open(fil) as f:
       path, name = os.path.split(fil)
       words_c = Counter([word for line in f for word in line.split()])
       for word in list:
           d2[name][word] = words_c[word]



#this portion is also for the generation of dictionary "prob",that is generated from file 2.txt can be overlooked!
with open('2.txt', 'r+') as istream:
for line in istream.readlines():
    try:
        k,r = line.strip().split(':')
        answer_ca[k.strip()].append(r.strip())
    except ValueError:
        print('Ignoring: malformed line: "{}"'.format(line))




#my problem lies here
items = d2.items()
small_d2 = dict(next(items) for _ in range(10))
for fil in list2:
    total=0
    for k,v in small_d2[fil].items():
        total=total+(v*answer_ca[k])
    print("Total of {} is {}".format(fil,total))
```

Comment: `float(d2[fil].values())` : `dict.values` returns a list not number, so applying `float()` on it is also an error.

Comment: yes i have rectified it!but the keyerror persists

Comment: I'm going to be honest, I have no idea what you're asking. Could you post a **minimal** code sample that illustrates your issue?

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: i have a separate list of files and a list of words, and also a dictionary that links them together.I need to find the sum of the dictionary values for every file.

Comment: You want sum of occurrences of a particular word in all files?

Comment: Try to keep the code you post down to an absolute minimum. Make every line that you show actually illustrate your question. No one wants to read 50+ lines of code when the problem could be shown in 10.

Comment: @i need to find the sum of the inner keys'(words) values for every outer key(file)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: no, please ignore that part, that part has been solved, i didn't want to elaborate on it!

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: my problem lies only in the final loop.

Comment: @PokerFace "sum of the dictionary values for every file" What does that mean? Also there are a million and one ways to link together two lists with a dictionary. Could you show some kind of example?

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: Say,d['the']['5.txt']=6,here "the" is my word and "5.txt" is the file.Now 6 is the number of times "the" occurs in "5.txt".Similarly,d['as']['5.txt']=2.I have around 100 files, and for each file, i need to find the sum of the dictionary values.So,here for 5.txt: i need my answer to be "6+2=8".I need this to be done for all the files.

Comment: @PokerFace Perfect! That should have been your question. I also think you mixed up the order of word and file here, but this short except exactly sums up everything you wanted to say and is imminently answerable. I personally suggest replacing your entire question with this.

Comment: @PokerFace In the code you're using `d2[name][word]` and in comment you said the structure is  : `d['the']['5.txt']` i.e `d2[word][name]`.
I am confused.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary  I am sorry the code is correct, i got confused!

Comment: @PokerFace what is `prob('as')`?

Comment: @PokerFace check out my updated solution.

Answer (score 0):

`with open(f) as fil` assigns fil to whatever the contents of f are. When you later access the entries in your dictionary as

```
total=sum(math.log(prob)*d2[fil][word].values())
```

I believe you mean

```
total = sum(math.log(prob)*d2[f][word])
```

though, this doesn't seem to quite match up with the order you were expecting, so I would instead suggest something more like this:

```
word_list = [#list of words]
file_list = [#list of files]
dictionary = {#your dictionary}
summation = lambda file_name,prob: sum([(math.log(prob)*dictionary[word][file_name]) for word in word_list])
return_value = []
for file_name in file_list:
    prob = #something
    return_value.append(summation(file_name))
```

The summation line there is defining an anonymous function within python. These are called lambda functions. Essentially, what that line in particular means is:

```
summation = lambda file_name,prob:
```

is almost the same as:

```
def summation(file_name, prob):
```

and then

```
sum([(math.log(prob)*dictionary[word][file_name]) for word in word_list])
```

is almost the same as:

```
result = []
for word in word_list:
    result.append(math.log(prob)*dictionary[word][file_name]
return sum(result)
```

so in total you have:

```
    summation = lambda file_name,prob: sum([(math.log(prob)*dictionary[word][file_name]) for word in word_list])
```

instead of:

```
def summation(file_name, prob):
    result = []
    for word in word_list:
        result.append(math.log(prob)*dictionary[word][file_name])
    return sum(result)
```

though the lambda function with the list comprehension is much faster than the for loop implementation. There are very few cases in python where one should use a for loop instead of a list comprehension, but they certainly exist.

Comment: i get a type error in this line:summation = lambda file_name, prob: sum([math.log(prob)*dictionary[word]["file_name"] for word in word_list]), it says:(lambda)() missing 1 required positional argument:'prob'

Comment: what does the line:summation = lambda file_name, prob: sum([math.log(prob)*dictionary[word]["file_name"] for word in word_list]) mean?

Comment: @PokerFace I imagine the keyerror is because there won't be any keys that are equal to the file contents, as that is some strange long string. Hence `f` instead of `fil`

Comment: In this line:return sum(result), why does it say invalid syntax?I am using python 3

Comment: @PokerFace oh, there was a missing paren from the above line.

Answer (score 0):

```
for fil in list2:  #list2 contains the filenames
    total = 0
    for k,v in d[fil].iteritems():
        total += v*log(prob[k])  #where prob is a dict

    print "Total of {} is {}".format(fil,total)
```

Comment: But i need the sum  to be (dic.values()*log(prob))..and it doesn't work as it is unsupported operand type

Comment: @PokerFace I suggest you to post some sample data and expected output, as the question is very very unclear.

Comment: i am sorry, but i have edited my code now, could you please check now, hope its clear!

Comment: each word has an associated probability "prob", so here, should i be considering prob(k) to be a dictionary with key value k=word?

Comment: @PokerFace yes, dict is going to be the best data-structure here with `word: prob` pairs.

Comment: i get 0 as output for all the files

Comment: @PokerFace try to debug it, print the value of v,k see what they return.

Comment: i get no output for k and v..they do not return anything

Comment: @PokerFace eh! how's that possible, did you replace `d` with `d2`? i.e `d[fil].iteritems()` should be `d2[fil].iteritems()`.

Comment: yes i did!..my code is:prob= collections.defaultdict(dict)
for word,count in counter.most_common():
    p=count/i
    prob[word]=math.log(p)
             


for fil in list2:  #list2 contains the filenames
    total = 0
    for k,v in d2[fil].items():
        total+=v*prob[k]  #where prob is a dict
    print ("Total of {} is {}".format(fil,total))

Comment: @PokerFace use `prob` as a normal dict, `prob ={}...`, if `d2` is not empty then this should work fine, post a small part of `d2` in question body.

Comment: when i try to print the whole of d2 i get a memory error, but it works fine when i check it individually,for ex:d2['10.txt][the] returns 12, which is correct

Comment: @PokerFace looks like the dict is huge.

Comment: so is there any other alternative that you could suggest?

Comment: @PokerFace extract a small part of d2 using this:
`items = d2.iteritems();small_d2 = dict(next(items) for _ in xrange(10))`.
Well I am going to sleep now, catch you later. :)

Comment: small_dict also doesn't work! i have posted my code..could you please help?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32999/discussion-between-poker-face-and-ashwini-chaudhary)